# Make spfx webpart working for guest users

Tags: spfx-webparts, external-users, guest-access

I made a simple hello world spfx web part by following the tutorial on the MS page. I published it, presented on my sharepoint online page and happy. But looks like, it only works for internal users. Guest users receive this error message:

> [SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]: Failed to load component
> "b3691b8c-374c-4c6d-956a-857272b91f06" (DemoWebPart). Original error:
> Failed to load path dependency "DemoWebPartStrings" from component
> "b3691b8c-374c-4c6d-956a-857272b91f06" (DemoWebPart). Original error:
> Error loading
> https://component-id.invalid/b3691b8c-374c-4c6d-956a-857272b91f06_0.0.1/DemoWebPartStrings
> Unable to load script
> https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/TestPnP/ClientSideAssets/dfab63f6-e983-42c1-be04-fe4ae0534a62/demo_-demowebpartstrings_en-us_536e65149b0acf4d52c0043073b9fc59.js

- I am  not using CDN, the application is published to the application
  catalog. I tried: Publishing the app on site collection application
  catalog instead
- Giving more and more rights to the test guest user,
  I even made it site collection administrator for both the tenant and
  the site collection app catalog, just to make sure it is not a
  permission problem.

None of these helped. Any advice welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Guest users don't have access to the app catalog. Take a look at this [article](https://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2020/03/23/spfx-web-part-assets-and-external-users.aspx), it explains the problem in more detail and how you can solve it.

Comment: Permissions checked. As described in the post, the guest user has already more than enough access: site collection admin on both the application catalog and the test site that contains the app. The site collection app catalog inherits permissions.